# GridView Click Display full screen image

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

i have Gridview that display Image from internet using universal-image-loader
i want when i click on image in gridview
show up in full screen

here is my simple code :

**MainActivity**

```
    Photoist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {
        //  String url = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getImgUrl();
        GridView lv = (GridView) parent;
        ImageView SelectedImage = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(pos-lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.iconImg);
        SelectedImage.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap myimage = SelectedImage.getDrawingCache();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FullScreenImageView.class);
        intent.putExtra("MyImageIntent", myimage);
        startActivity(intent);

        }

});
```

**FullScreenImageView.Class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        ImageView Fullscreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        Bitmap Image = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("MyImageIntent");
        Fullscreen.setImageBitmap(Image);
}
```

The Error in this Code :

```
Fullscreen.setImageBitmap(Image);
```

i hope someone can help
and i have 1 more question
how i can make the FullScreenImage Swipe/Slide . i mean if i slide image left it show next image, and i slide it right show previews image .

-sorry for my bad english, and thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Try this when getting the Bitmap from your ImageView:

```
Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)SelectedImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Bitmap class implements parcelable, which means that it's instances can be stored in a parcel.
Parcel by the way is just androids way of serialization.

Change

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("MyImageIntent");
```

to

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MyImageIntent");
```

For the slide part you want to create a ViewPager which was designed for exactly that.

Comment: Not working same error 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo FullScreenImageView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: #edit 

 Bitmap myimage = ((BitmapDrawable)SelectedImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

trying now ,

Comment: Change your variable to names to start with a lower-case letter: `image` instead of `Image`.

Comment: still not working,, same error :( error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo FullScreenImageView}: java.lang.NullPointerException  - for some reason i cant use Fullscreen.setImageBitmap

Comment: @SamAyoub95 Are you sure you are getting the correct item from the `parent` object? Try to Log `myimage` content before attaching it to your intent.

Comment: how i can log image? 

any way i used  Log.e("Test ",myimage.toString());

and it show "android.graphics.Bitmap@413a3018" in logcat

Comment: @SamAyoub95 Now do the same when you receive the intent in another activity and check if it's null there.

Comment: i dont think so, because i tried to change FullScreen ImageView from MainActivity without any Intent , and still have same error

Comment: okey, i tried 
android.graphics.Bitmap@41404620
after intent
android.graphics.Bitmap@413498b8

Comment: @SamAyoub95 `activity_second.xml` seems to miss your ImageView with id: `imgDisplay`.

Comment: Omg ya xD fixed and now its works 

but there is problem that image is very low quality, [while the original one from url is high quality]

Comment: maybe i should get the original one from the adapter, can you Guide me ?